# What does an ellipsis do in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I'm familiar with the basic [range operator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732):

```
.. Range operator
Represents the sequential integers in an integer array, given an upper and lower boundary.
    1..10
    10..1
    foreach ($a in 1..$max) {write-host $a}
```

However, I accidently used an ellipsis (`...`) instead of a range operator (`..`) today, and noticed it enumerated from N down to 0 for some reason:

```
PS C:\> 5...3
5
4
3
2
1
0
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The range operator is still being used - as it turns out, the second input (in this case, `.3`) to the range operator is being implicitly cast to an integer, since the range operator only accepts integers as inputs.

This can be verified by using a right-side value higher than `.5`:

```
PS C:\> 5...6
5
4
3
2
1
```

This is much easier to see when you use an obviously non-integer value as the right-side value for the range operator:

```
PS C:\> 5..'3'
5
4
3
```

Comment: Nice answer :) powershell continues to amaze, eh? ;)